# Deprecated or invalid utility class SLDS

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, vs-code, sfdx-plugin

I have been trying to use SLDS in LWC. However, I am noticing these issues recently. The same style classes were working before without any issues.

Does anything worng with my VS code or is really these classes are deprecated?

I am trying this
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/lookups/

[image]

Comment: Check if you have installed Slds validator extension.

Comment: yes, installed.

Comment: Yes, these are deprecated as far as I know. For example, looking at this latest release notes (https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/release-notes/), I see the following Deprecated slds-form_compound for slds-form-element_compound. I always wondered if there was an easy way or tool to check if my components were using the deprecated SLDS CSS class and I learned that this is built into Salesforce DX. It comes with the VS Code environment when you install the "Salesforce Extensions for VS Code" package.

 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode

Comment: @AnudeepGopagoni Consider posting your comment as an answer. :)

Comment: Posted per your recommendation @Raul. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes are indeed deprecated. For example, if we search for Form Element in the latest [Lightning Design System documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) (Summer'20 (SLDS 2.12.2)), we see the usage as follows

```
<div class="slds-form-element"></div>
```

**Note**: Deprecated slds-form_compound for slds-form-element_compound

[image]

Salesforce Extensions for VS Code has the ability to identify deprecated classes. I recommend looking at the latest release documentation to ensure if the SLDS classes used in your components are in parity with the SLDS documentation.

Comment: yes, VS Code is giving updated tags for the deprecated ones.

Answer (score 0):

When referencing one of these tags that I wanted ignored in my JS code... I broke the text string up to prevent the validator from seeing it...

```
return 'slds-p-around_medium';
```

becomes:

```
return 'slds' + '-p-around_medium';
```

Viola!  The validator cannot "see" the class and ignores it.